# Center QLabel derived widget inside a QScrollArea

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

How should I center my QLabel derived widget `papyrus` inside a QScrollArea?

```
QScrollArea *scroll_area = new QScrollArea(this);
scroll_area->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter);
scroll_area->setWidgetResizable(true);
scroll_area->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
papyrus = new Papyrus(scroll_area);
scroll_area->setWidget(papyrus);
setCentralWidget(scroll_area);
resize(800, 600);
```

This is the snippet I am using but my widget sticks to the top left...

Comment: Calling `scroll_area->setWidgetResizable(true);` you instruct scroll area to resize your label, so it will always have the size of your scroll area. I would suggest to turn this property off.

Comment: I realize this is an old question but you should consider accepting one of the two answers if either one worked for you so the question is marked accordingly

Answer (score 0):

(main.cpp example):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "MainWindow.h"

#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLabel label("Label");
    label.setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter);

    QScrollArea area;
    area.setWidgetResizable(true);

    area.setWidget(&label);
    area.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```